# Incorrect 301 redirect target url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, seo

My 301 redirect rule appends the 3rd url directory to the new directory which is not what i am looking to achieve.

Eg : Redirect 301 /services/tech-services/techserv2/ https://www.domain.co.za/our-services/

redirects to https://www.domain.co.za/our-services/techserv2 instead of just https://www.domain.co.za/our-services/

The redirect rules in the htaccess file looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please assist.

Comment: I would suggest asking this in a server help site, rather than a programming one such as : https://serverfault.com/

Comment: `Redirect` matches on path _prefixes_, and appends anything extra that followed that prefix in the original URL, to the new target. If you don’t want that, then use a RewriteRule to make this redirect.